# How to sort google-sheet table according to version number column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a gsheet [table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OZj2cNJb5f67O0aZKsPhFLwheV5fqO2K2Uovv43Tq8o/edit?usp=sharing) with columns: `version, valueA`

I wrote an app-script function that compares two versions:

```
function sortAnalyticsVersionsDesc() {
  var versions = activeSpreadsheet.getRangeByName(MY_RANGE).getValues().filter(item => item[0] != "");
  versions.sort(_compareVer);
}
```

I want the `valueA` to be sorted accordingly.

How can I use this custom `comperator` to sort the whole table according to this logic?

From the documentation it seems not possible.

[sortSpecObj](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)    `The columns to sort by` gives no option to provide a custom sorting function.

Do I have to copy the whole table to memory? But even then - how do I sort a matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should take the whole table and re-write it.

```
function sortAnalyticsVersionsDesc() {
  var lines = activeSpreadsheet.getRangeByName(ANALYTICS_DATA_TABLE).getValues().filter(item => item[0] != "");
  lines = lines.sort(_compareLinesWithVer);
  activeSpreadsheet.getRangeByName(ANALYTICS_DATA_TABLE).setValues(lines)
}
    
    function _compareLinesWithVer(a, b) {
    return _compareVer(a[2], b[2]);
    }
    
    function _compareVer(a, b) {
    
    ...}
```